# WxGo Grid Cell renderer

Tags: go, wxwidgets, wxgo

I'm obviously missing some basic understanding of either Go or Wx Widgets.

I'm trying to create a very basic table with checkboxes in the first column.

```
table := wx.NewGrid(w, wx.ID_ANY)
table.CreateGrid(4, 2)
table.SetCellEditor(0, 0, wx.SwigIsGridCellBoolRenderer{})
```

That code gives me this error:

```
invalid type for composite literal: wx.SwigIsGridCellBoolRenderer
```

I know I also have to set the editor. But I'm not even that far. The more detailed the answer, the better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error hints you are using a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), which can be used to create values of struts, slices, arrays, maps or derivatives of these.

This:

```
wx.SwigIsGridCellBoolRenderer{}
```

Would be an empty composite literal of the type `wx.SwigIsGridCellBoolRenderer`, but that type is nether of the types you may use with a composite literal. It is an interface type:

```
type SwigIsGridCellBoolRenderer interface {
    SwigGetGridCellBoolRenderer() GridCellBoolRenderer
}
```

`wx.NewGrid()` returns a type of `wx.Grid` which is an interface with a method:

```
SetCellEditor(arg2 int, arg3 int, arg4 SwigIsGridCellEditor)
```

So you have to pass a value to it that satisfies / implements the `wx.SwigIsGridCellEditor` interface.

This interface has a single method:

```
type SwigIsGridCellEditor interface {
    SwigGetGridCellEditor() GridCellEditor
}
```

So any type that has such `SwigGetGridCellEditor()` method may be used here. Such types are:

- `wx.SwigClassGridCellTextEditor`
- `wx.SwigClassGridCellAutoWrapStringEditor`
- `wx.SwigClassGridCellBoolEditor`
- `wx.SwigClassGridCellChoiceEditor`
- `wx.SwigClassGridCellEnumEditor`
- etc.

So create an instance of one of the above, that you can pass to `table.SetCellEditor()`.

For example:

```
editor := wx.NewGridCellTextEditor()
table.SetCellEditor(0, 0, editor)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'm rebuilding my workstation right now. I'll test early next week!

Comment: @Chemdream I'm glad. Then you should accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Sorry, thought I did.